# How can I assign integers to character variables so that arithmetic functions can be performed on those integers when I enter a String in java

Tags: java, string, integer

For example,
If I assign `char A=1`, `char B=2`, `char C=3` and so on..
Then when I enter a string I want to be able to perform arithmetic addition operation on the respective integer values assigned to respective characters i.e., I want to add the integer values I assigned to characters when I enter a string e.g, If I enter the string `ABC` output must be 6 i.e., `A+B+C`.

My code is as follows:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.lang.Character;


public class AddName extends javax.swing.JFrame {


    public AddName() {
        initComponents();
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setText("Name");

        jTextField1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N

        jButton1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jButton1.setText("Save");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jButton2.setText("Back");
        jButton2.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                jButton2MouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(39, 39, 39)
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 118, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(43, 43, 43)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jButton1)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jButton2)
                        .addGap(41, 41, 41))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 195, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addContainerGap(208, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(103, 103, 103)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 29, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 29, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(124, 124, 124)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                    .addComponent(jButton2))
                .addContainerGap(155, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton2MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
    FrontPage fr= new FrontPage();
    fr.setVisible(true);
    dispose();// TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                     

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
     try
        {
            String name=jTextField1.getText();
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");   //to load driver
            Connection   con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root","chinu1995");//URL:path of database            
            PreparedStatement st1=con.prepareStatement("select * from NameTable where name=?");
            st1.setString(1,name);
            ResultSet rs=st1.executeQuery();

            if(rs.next())
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Name Already Available");
            }

            else{

            PreparedStatement st=con.prepareStatement("insert  into   NameTable  values(?)");
            st.setString(1,name);
            st.executeUpdate();

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Name inserted successfully");
            } 
//            int sumChars(String charStr) {
//    int sum = 0;
//    for (int i = 0; i < charStr.length(); i++) {
//        sum += (charStr.charAt(i) - 'A') + 1;

//    return sum;


           //String add= jTextField1.getText();

          // for(int i=0;i<=add.length();i++){

             //int num = Character.getNumericValue(A);//charAt(0);//+add.charAt(i+1);
              //jTextField2.setText(Integer.toString(num));
         //  }



        }catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();//exception name+ line no

        }         // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AddName.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AddName.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AddName.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AddName.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new AddName().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: This is a weird thing to want to do, but yes you can do it provided that you define the operation on chars as addition. Just write some method `int sumChars(char[] array) {..}`

Comment: Thank you @Kon but I didn't exactly understood how to use the method you suggested.. Can you please give a lil example for the same?

Comment: What characters/letters do you want to do this with? How will you handle different case? If all you care about are upper case A-Z, then you can simply subtract 64 from each char.

Comment: Thanks Brett I'll try it and will then tell whether it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have only upper case A-Z, then you can try this:

```
int sumChars(String charStr) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < charStr.length(); i++) {
        sum += (charStr.charAt(i) - 'A') + 1;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

call method:

```
sumChars("ABC")
```

return 6

OR, if you have all the values and their not so much, you can use the `Map`:

```
private static final Map<Character, Integer> CONST_CHAR_INT_MAP =
        Collections.unmodifiableMap(new HashMap<Character, Integer>() {{
            put('A', 1);
            put('B', 2);
            put('C', 3);
            // ...
        }});

public int charAt(char c) {
    return CONST_CHAR_INT_MAP.get(c);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Svichkarev for the help, and apologies for late reply. Btw why can't the logic can be used for lower case letters? And which logic will work for both the cases i.ee, Lower and Upper both?

Comment: I tried the method you suggested but netbeans is suggesting me that this method is not a valid method.

Comment: So I wanna ask if its a predefined method or a generic or  am I supposed to define it as my own method?

Comment: If you want to use the logic for both cases, you can use `Character.toUpperCase( charStr.charAt(i) )` for every char from the string.

Comment: Define it as your own method, it is not predefined method.

Comment: I added my code too in my question so could you please tell me how and where should I declare this method?

Comment: You can declare this method in your class `AddName`, right after the class declaration as private method (write `private` before declaration). Do not place the method in the `jButton1ActionPerformed` method.

Comment: Thank you your logic worked for me but actually I want to assign some other integer values to the characters such as 'A=3', 'B=5' or something like that? Can you help me with that too please?

Comment: If my answer helped, you can put the accepted answer. How much flexibility do you want to solve the problem? If it's just a constant offset, you can add a parameter for the displacement. If this is a complex solution, it can be used to specify the mapping HashMap letter to number.

Comment: Actually I have some constant integer values that I want to assign to them and those values will be same for every character they won't change. I can provide you those values I wanna assign to every integer if you want so that you could actually help me in a better way. And yeah thanks a lot for helping this much. Your solution was not the exact answer I wanted but yeah it still helped. So please solve this last problem.

Comment: If I have correctly understood the problem, then there is a solution. I have added another option to respond.

Comment: I'll try then tell if it works but really thank you so much for helping me this far. Thanks a lot. :):)

Comment: Please tell me how to use this code in my code because i m tired of trying to fit it in. And also how will I be able to insert the result of the sum of values assigned to characters into my database table.